# Is it possible to zip multiple files without a parent directory on macOS?

Tags: macos, zip

I have two files that I would like to zip, `a.txt` and `b.txt`. I'd like to zip them into a file, called `my.zip`, in such a way that when `my.zip` is unzipped, the two files are placed into the current directory *without* being placed in a directory of any kind.

This is what I have tried so far, from within the directory that contains both files:

```
zip ../my.zip *
```

and

```
zip -j my.zip a.txt b.txt
```

Those commands create a file called `my-zip` that when unzipped, creates a *directory* called `my-zip`, with the two files inside of it. Instead, I'd like the files to be placed into the current directory, without being contained in a directory called `my-zip`.

EDIT:

To clarify, the way I am unzipping it is by double-clicking the zip file via Finder on OS X

Comment: I just did this on my linux (Mint 19).  `touch a.txt; touch b.txt; zip my.zip *; rm *.txt`.  Then `unzip my.zip`.  Bingo, `a.txt` and `b.txt` in the local directory.  Are you sure your `zip` command is not an alias defining some default options?  EDIT: I tried it with `zip ../my.zip *`, and no difference, no directory is created on unzip.

Answer (score 0):

How did you unzip the `my.zip` file? I just tried your commands and worked fine as expected. Commands that I ran,

```sh
$ zip my.zip a.txt b.txt
$ unzip my.zip
```

However, when I right click the file `my.zip` (in Nautilus file manager) and click 'Extract Here', it creates a folder called `my` and puts the contents in there.

Comment: You're right about this - it seems to be caused from opening this via Finder in macOS